# Code to locate a specific item in a linked list and remove it

Tags: linked-list

For my Computer Science course we are needing to create 2 functions. One function needs to locate the serial position of the item being searched for (an int in this case) and the index of the previous item. The locateNode function (the function described above) needs to be used within the Remove function as well as other functions already written by the professor in the class. Remove is simply supposed to take the item before the one being removed and make it point to the item that was being pointed to by the removed item. Finally it will take the removed node and push it into an avail list within the same array (essentially there are 2 linked lists in the one array.) My functions are giving me the wrong output and I currently do not know which is wrong or if both functions are wrong.

```
void SortedList::Remove(ItemType anItem, bool& success)
//                      IN               OUT
{
    int previous, position;
    success=locateNode(anItem, previous, position);
    cerr<<success<<endl;
    if (success)
   {
        int current=list[0].next;
       list[previous].next=list[list[previous].next].next;
       for (int i=1; i<position; i++)
        {
            current=list[i].next;
        }
        PushAvail(current);
    }
} // end Remove

bool SortedList::locateNode(
ItemType anItem, int& previous, int& position) const
{
 position=1;
 previous=0;
int current=list[0].next;
bool isPresent = false;
for (int count=1; count <= size; count++)
{
    if (list[current].item >= anItem)
    {
        if ( list[current].item == anItem)
        {
            cerr<<"Position "<< position<< endl;
            cerr<<"Previous "<< previous<< endl;
            isPresent = true;
        }
        return isPresent;
    }
    position++;
    previous=list[previous].next;
    current=list[current].next;
}
return isPresent;
}
```